# StoreRequestParameters,get the values issue

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

on the web service side I am applying

```
     StoreRequestParameters parameters = new StoreRequestParameters(this.Context);
      string  condition= parameters.GridFilters.ToString();
//I ma sending this to the methot "List<Ks> Get(....)"
```

to get the gridfilter parameters.

inside  the other methot ,trying to get the  selected gridfilters values like this.

```
    public List<Ks> Get(int start, int limit, string sort, string terssiralama, string condition, out int totalrow)
    {
         FilterConditions fc = new FilterConditions(condition);


                        foreach (FilterCondition cnd in fc.Conditions)
                        {
                            Comparison comparison = cnd.Comparison;
                            string fi = cnd.Field;
                            FilterType type = cnd.Type;

                            switch (cnd.Type)
                            {
                                case FilterType.Date:
                                    switch (comparison)
                                    {
                                        case Comparison.Eq:
                                            field1 = cnd.Field;
                                            cmp1 = "=";
                                            value1 = cnd.Value<string>();
...........
..........
}
```

but I failed getting the values like this

```
 FilterConditions fc = new FilterConditions(condition);
```

I couldnt pass the string values .
should I serializes or deserilized first ?

Comment: obj = this.Context.Request["filter"]; fix the problem

Comment: If this is the correct answer, post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 StoreRequestParameters parameters = new StoreRequestParameters(this.Context);
 instead of using  this, string  condition= parameters.GridFilters.ToString();
 I use this 
 string  obj = this.Context.Request["filter"]; 
 and pass it to the 

FilterConditions fc = new FilterConditions(obj);
It can be reach all filter condition in fc filtercondition variable.
```